# Custom error message displyed only while debugging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this entry in my web config.

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/ErrorPage.aspx" />
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">.
```

Basically I am trying to show custom error page whenever there is an unhandled exception in the application. I get the custom error page only when I am debugging the application i.e. when w3wp(worker) process is attached. It shows the YSOD (yellow screen of death), which includes the exception details when not debugging.

I am obviously missing something here?

Comment: Just to clarify, 'custom errors' means the user-friendly error page, which you're defining as ErrorPage.aspx.  The opposite of the custom error page is the YSOD (yellow screen of death), which includes the exception details.  You may want to clarify your question by using wording other than 'generic error page'.

Comment: @Sean edited my question. Thanks for taking a look!!!

Comment: Which status code you got?

Comment: I am getting status as 500